# htaccess & RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess

Wondering if this is possible at all.

I'm using htaccess to rewrite my pages, and i'm using the following line:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9^-]+)$ page.php?page=$1
```

to rewrite it into clean links. page.php then calls the data appropriately.
I am wondering though if its possible, that if the variable is 3 characters long it redirects to another page.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9^-]+{3})$ small.php?char=$1
```

Something similar the above? Is that possible? I just stuck the {3} for illustration purposes.
For example if my address was www.example.com/abc, it would redirect to small.php?char=abc and if it was any longer it would redirect to the page.php address.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to create an if statement that if matched will redirect the user to the given link.  The RewriteCond defines a rule condition, there can be more than one and if all of them are matched the subsequent RewriteRule is used:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /^([a-zA-Z0-9^-]+{3})$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9^-]+{3})$ small.php?char=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9^-]+)$ page.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try simply this without the `+`, putting the small.php rule before and adding L flags (Last), so that if it matches the small version it will exit:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9^-]{3})$ small.php?char=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9^-]+)$ page.php?page=$1     [L]
```

`+` stands for one or more characters. `{3}` stands for exactly 3 chars.